# what is scrollViewDidScroll means?

Tags: uitableview, swift, uiscrollviewdelegate

I want to know this override function named "scrollViewDidScroll"means because i am now currently stuck at that which that doesn't work.Here is my code.I really want to know each steps by steps of the code i describe below.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    // UITableView only moves in one direction, y axis
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y //?
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height //?
    // Change 10.0 to adjust the distance from bottom
        if (maximumOffset - currentOffset) <= 40.0 { //?
            loadSegment(currentPage, count: currentCount) // This is the function that load 15 results per page each call from api. 
        }
}
```

I am now currently stuck at page 2 with "Loading" when i scroll down after getting 30 results which mean this method is not working after i scroll first from page 2.When i scroll down from page 2 to get more results,it stuck at loading which mean this method dont work.So loadSegment don't call because it dont pass to if condition.

Any help with code explanation?Thank You

Answer (score 1):

If `scrollViewDidScroll` isn't firing, you should probably check if `tableview.delegate = self;` or `tableview.delegate = // whichever class scrollViewDidScroll is in` Have you put an `NSLog` in `scrollViewDidScroll`?